# Html Agility Pack - New HtmlAttribute

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Using Html Agility Pack in C# I have a node I'd like to add an attribute to.

Currently the node is an `<li>` element with no attributes and I'd like to add a class to it of "active".

It looks like the best thing to use would be `node.Attributes.Add(attrClass)`

Where `attrClass` is a `HtmlAttribute` of `class="active"`.

However if I try to define a new `HtmlAttribute` I get an error stating that it doesn't have any constructors. Eg `HtmlAttribute attrClass = new HtmlAttribute();`

Is there something wrong with my Html Agility Pack reference, or am I doing something incorrectly?

Is there another method I could use to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
node.Attributes.Add("class","active");
```

Answer (score 6):

The `HtmlAttribute` class has one constructor, which is `internal`. Therefore you'd not have access to actually call it, thus you'd get an error either way.

However, it is exposed elsewhere, under the `HtmlDocument` class.

So:

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
var attribute = document.CreateAttribute("class", "active");
```

You then have a `HtmlAttribute` representing the `class` attribute with a value of `active`.