# Add CSS Class to All Tags in TagBuilder, Edit Existing Attribute

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-core, tagbuilder

How do I go through all the Tags in a Tagbuilder, both All Outer and Inner Elements, and Append "test" to their CSS class .

```
tagbuilder.AddCssClass("test");
```

Is there a way to loop through  all element tags ?

Comment: You can't.  That is not what TagBuilder was designed for.  It's not called, HTMLBuilder or TagSbuilder, but TagBuilder.  Per the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2) every constructor/method/property refers to a single *element*.

Comment: then how do I edit a Dom tree in C#?  I received code from a Dom tree from TagHelper

Comment: or how can I separate all the inner html tags into multiple tag builders?

Comment: You can't and you can't using TagBuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the best package for parsing HTML is [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/).

Using this package you can easily select necessary nodes and add class attribute.

It can be done like in example below:

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
var node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input[contains(@class, 'example')]").FirstOrDefault();
node.Attributes.Add("class","test");
```

For more details please review next StackOverflow topics:

- [TagBuilder Find Specific Inner Element and Add New Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57121099/tagbuilder-find-specific-inner-element-and-add-new-attribute/57220152#57220152)
- [Html Agility Pack - New HtmlAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400619/html-agility-pack-new-htmlattribute)