# TagBuilder Find Specific Inner Element and Add New Attribute

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a TagBuilder which contains Outer and Inner Elements. How do I traverse to the Input level line , and Add the following as an New attribute?

`placeholder="Search"`

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="cont label-outside">
        <label>Name</label>
        <div class="group">
            <input type="text" required="required" class="focusedOut">
            <span class="highlight"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="close-button" onclick="clear()"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If no Tagbuilder/Taghelper method exists, should C# HTML Agility package be utilized to edit tag tree?  https://html-agility-pack.net/traversing ; If yes, how to convert Tagbuilder/ or Taghelper Output into Agility Package HTMLDocument?

*This is different from question [Add CSS Class to All Tags in TagBuilder, Edit Existing Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57119863/add-css-class-to-all-tags-in-tagbuilder-edit-existing-attribute)  as this asks to Edit existing attribute. Question here is about Adding New Attribute.  See article below :

[Why isn't it good to ask multiple questions and answers in one question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371614/why-isnt-it-good-to-ask-multiple-questions-and-answers-in-one-question)

Comment: Can we see your TagBuilder?

Comment: well it contains all the elements above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your task you can use [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/).

Using **HtmlAgilityPack** you can use **XPath Query** to select necessary nodes and add tag to this node.

To select nodes you can use [SelectNodes](https://html-agility-pack.net/select-nodes) method:

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input[contains(@class, 'focusedOut')]");
```

To add attribute you can use [Attributes Collection](https://html-agility-pack.net/attributes):

```
node.Attributes.Add("placeholder","Search");
```

Comment: curious why TagBuilder never allowed parsing html, seems like HtmlAgilitypack is better in all respects, as I noted in question,  not sure even what point of Tagbuilder is anymore, thanks

Comment: Yes HtmlAgilitypack is very powerful library for HTML parsing. This library works with .NET and .NET Core. So you can use it in your project.